# ALTER DATABASE MODIFY FILE fails - I want to alter data file sizes using size = @variable - not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, type-conversion

Example:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @DBname NVARCHAR(128), @FileName NVARCHAR(128), @NewSizeMB INT

SET @DBname = 'AGTestDB'
SET @FileName = 'AGTestDB'
SET @NewSizeMB = 1024

SET @sql = N'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBname + 
                N'] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = ' + @FileName +    
                N', SIZE = ' + @NewSizeMB +
                N' );';
```

returns an error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ALTER DATABASE [AGTestDB] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = AGTestDB, SIZE = ' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator only means concatenation when both operands are of character data type; in your case one of them is an `INT`, and, according to the data type conversion [precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When an operator combines expressions of different data types, the data type with the lower precedence is first converted to the data type with the higher precedence.

`INT` has higher precedence than any character data type. Clearly the other operand, the string `'ALTER DATABASE etc.'` cannot be converted to an integer.

Use `CONCAT()` for concatenation or explicitly `CAST()` your `@NewSizeMB` to a character type.